# Where can I download Fujitsu COBOL 3 or 4

Tags: cobol, netcobol

I'm looking for fujitsu COBOL 3 or 4. According to the website of NetCobol, it was delivered with some old books.

If you know some titles of those books, I can search for them and buy them.

(I already found COBOL for Dummies, but that book is unavailble for sending to my country (Belgium))

Many thanks,

Yvan

Answer (score 1):

From the **[NetCobol](http://www.alchemysolutions.com/support/Previous-Versions)** website:

> Fujitsu COBOL (an earlier name for Fujitsu NetCOBOL) versions 3 and 4 are included in many COBOL books that were published in the run up to the new millennium. Some of these books are still being sold today, providing excellent material for learning COBOL. These versions of Fujitsu COBOL were great products for COBOL students but were designed to run on Windows 95 and Windows 98. Consequently they no longer work with current versions of Windows. If you have received one of these products in a COBOL text book, your only option for using them is to find an older computer that still has Windows 95 or Windows 98 – an increasingly rare item.

You might want to look into **[OpenCobol](http://www.opencobol.org/)** or **[Cobol-IT](http://www.cobol-it.com/)** standard.

Comment: @Yvan Janssens. Another "solution" might be to buy the current version of NetCOBOL from AlchenySolutions. But from what I have heard, OpenCobol is a pretty good choice too - and it is free.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SAMS "Teach Yourself COBOL In 24 Hours" by Thane Hubbell has Fujitsu COBOL v3 included on the disk. The book is listed on amazon.co.uk.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found COBOL for dummies :). I found it in "De Sleghte" - it's a popular bookstore for second hand books here in Belgium.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Raincode](https://www.raincode.com/technical-landscape/techs/) free Cobol. There is a Linux and windows installer!
I am following an online course and to compile I used their free cobol. Easy to use.

Comment: Links are great, but it would be even more helpful if you could summarize a possible way to correct the problem outlined in the question.